# Filtered Questions in iPhone app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ios-app-feed

It would be great to have access "Filtered Questions" (maybe under global feed) in iPhone app.

I'm aware of "tags" feature for specific site, but i'm using more complex filter (search on multiple sites) in "Filtered Questions" on stackexchange.com and it would be great to have ascess to same filters on phone.

Bonus points would go for notifications for new entries under "Filtered Questions".